# Sphero Oval - Streaming C execution - Any more info on it

Tags: sphero-api, sphero

So I picked up my sphero today - it had been gathering dust for a year or so - thought I'd get back to writing some orbBasic stuff.
Visited their site and found this:
http://sdk.sphero.com/robot-languages/oval-oval-language/

But I can't find any information about how to stream the instructions end control the execution. Is this still work in progress? Maybe an accidental leak?

If it is available, that would be great. I can't seem to follow orbBasic stuff I'd written over a year ago. Not a fan of managing line numbers and figuring out what those variables hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oval is a feature in Ollie and soon to be a feature in Sphero 2.0!  Both the Android and iOS SDKs will be released on Github to support Oval at the same time as the firmware update enabling Oval.

Comment: Thanks. Can't wait, already have an oval script ready for my sphero 2.

Answer (score 1):

Get the new Sphero SPRK app from the apple app store.  It includes the firmware upgrade that enables Oval on Sphero 2.0.